# Javascript Slideshow with changing page background

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'd like to know if it's possible to achieve something like this slider automatically with javascript/jquery:

http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/TheSource/

Notice how the slider background changes according to the edge of the slider image. This can be seen easily on higher resolutions.

My objective would be to:

*Add a fixed resolution image to the slider and then the background of that image would be "calculated" automatically with JS and create a smooth gradient.*

I'm not sure if i made my point clear, so if you have any question please ask.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the jQuery.cycle plugin?

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Creating the slider itself is not the problem, but instead, changing the page background acording to the image being shown